# Xampp with Joomla not configured correctly

Tags: php, macos, joomla

I've been configuring Joomla to work on my PC using Xampp.
At work I have it configured for a Mac with OSX server.
I imported my database to the new SQL tables, and brought all my Joomla files over.
Almost everything seems to be working other then a few things.

This information here gets put on the top of all my files, and it also shows a page of it before it loads to the next page:

`Mac OS X   2��ATTR;������com.apple.quarantine0001;53c81c76;Firefox.app;This resource fork intentionally left blank ��Mac OS X  2��ATTR;������com.apple.quarantine0001;53c81c76;Firefox.app;This resource fork intentionally left blank ��Mac OS X`

I'm not sure why this is. Some images don't work as well. I looked it up but I don't see it anywhere.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you've copied across some of the invisible Mac specific files (`.DS_Store`, `.CFUserTextEncoding` etc) and possibly some of the invisible directories (e.g. `.Trash`).

Either way this is not the best way to copy an existing Joomla site to your development environment as you will experience problems like this one and possibly permissions issues.

I would recommend that you go and [download the free](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download.html) and well-thought-of "[Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html)" and [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html). [Install Akeeba Backup on your live site and make a backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation.html).

Then copy the unzipped Akeeba Kickstart to your Xampp setup along with the newly created backup file(s) and step through [the process of restoring the site](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-kickstart-documentation.html) to your local setup.

All up this should take about 10-15 minutes (plus download/upload times etc) and will result in a near perfect copy of your site. (I say near perfect as you Xampp is likely to have different versions of PHP, MySQL etc and of course is a different Operating System).